# How to check whether include(CPack) is already being called before or not in CMake?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I am working on a project that uses a third party source as a submodule. In the third party source of the CMakeLists.txt they have `include(CPack)` in their CMakeLists.txt, and this is causing problems because when I write my own `include(CPack)` in the CMakeLists.txt of my project, I get cmake config warnings like

```
CPack.cmake has already been included!!
```

and all the CPack variables I wrote are overwritten by the third party source, which causes errors when I run `make package`

I attempted `add_subdirectory(third-party-source EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)`, which ignores all the `install` calls in the third party source, but unfortunately it didn't ignore the CPack calls.

Is there a way for me to add something like

```
if(CPACK_ALREADY_INCLUDED)
  include(CPack)
endif()
```

in the third party source to work around this problem?

Comment: `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` applies only to targets created in that directory and below, so there is absolutely no reason it would ignore an `include()` directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override 3rd-party misbehavior is never easy. This is why I personally do not favor `add_subdirectory` and prefer to use `vcpkg` or another build orchestration tool (like Conan) instead.

However, the following snippet should work:

```
function (add_third_party)
  # Write an empty CPack module
  file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/override/CPack.cmake" "")
  set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/override;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
  add_subdirectory(third-party-source)
endfunction ()

add_third_party()
```

This will create a blank CPack module and trick the third party code into including it rather than the standard module. The function exists to make sure this overriding behavior can't leak out into the rest of your build.

---

*I had misread your question. I thought you were in control of the project that included `CPack`.*

Yes, the variable is named `CPack_CMake_INCLUDED`. However, it is better to check whether you are the top-level project and conditionally include your packaging rules, like this:

```
string(COMPARE EQUAL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" is_top_level)
option(MyProj_INCLUDE_PACKAGING "Include packaging rules for MyProj" "${is_top_level}")

if (MyProj_INCLUDE_PACKAGING)
    # ...
    include(CPack)
endif ()
```

Comment: `CPack_CMake_INCLUDED` actually works. I wonder why it's not mentioned in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html

Comment: Not sure. It's been in the sources for ages, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
# include CPack if it's not included yet
if(CPack_CMake_INCLUDED EQUAL 1)
    include(CPack)
endif()
```